# Dynamically added inputs don't show up in $_POST data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I tried searching around the web for a solution to this problem, but couldn't find any. The problem is - I have a form, and a button with a javascript function, that adds additional inputs. After passing these input variables to php `$_POST` array, it prints out everything except the dynamically created inputs. Do you guys know, why the dynamically generated inputs don't show up?

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" id="rekins">
   <p>Invoice Number: <input type="text" name="nr" /></p>
   <p>Account: <input type="text" name="konts" /></p>
   <h1>Services:</h1>
   <h2>1. Service</h2>
   <input type="text" name="pak[0][counter]" style="display:none" value="1"/>
   <p>Name<input name="pak[0][name]" type="text" id="pakName0" class="pak"/></p>
   <p>Count<input name="pak[0][count]" type="text" id="pakCount0" class="pak"/></p>
   <p>Price<input name="pak[0][Price]" type="text" id="pakPrice0" class="pak"/></p>
   <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add another service" />
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
    fields = 0;
    function addInput() {
    fields += 1;
    document.getElementById('rekins').innerHTML += 
            "<h2>"+(fields+1)+". service</h2>"+
            "<input type='text' name='pak["+fields+"][counter]' style='display:none' value='"+(fields+1)+"'/>"+
            "<p>Name<input name='pak["+fields+"][name]' type='text' id='pakName"+fields+"' class='pak'/></p>"+
            "<p>Count<input name='pak["+fields+"][count]' type='text' id='pakCount"+fields+"' class='pak'/></p>"+
            "<p>Price<input name='pak["+fields+"][Price]' type='text' id='pakPrice"+fields+"' class='pak'/></p>";
    }
</script>
```

I tried debugging with `var_dump($_POST['pak']);` and the default values were shown but not the dynamically added ones.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you testing the code with IE browser ? Try other browser e.g., mozilla

Comment: Tried on both Chrome and Firefox, same results...

Comment: then check the `$_POST` printing code. As i have tested your code in firefox and chrome, it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and its work for me.

Html side :

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="x.php" method="POST" id="rekins">
       <p>Invoice Number: <input type="text" name="nr" /></p>
       <p>Account: <input type="text" name="konts" /></p>
       <h1>Services:</h1>
       <h2>1. Service</h2>
       <input type="text" name="pak[0][counter]" style="display:none" value="1"/>
       <p>Name<input name="pak[0][name]" type="text" id="pakName0" class="pak"/></p>
       <p>Count<input name="pak[0][count]" type="text" id="pakCount0" class="pak"/></p>
       <p>Price<input name="pak[0][Price]" type="text" id="pakPrice0" class="pak"/></p>
       <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add another service" />
       <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
        fields = 0;
        function addInput() {
        fields += 1;
        document.getElementById('rekins').innerHTML += 
                "<h2>"+(fields+1)+". service</h2>"+
                "<input type='text' name='pak["+fields+"][counter]' style='display:none' value='"+(fields+1)+"'/>"+
                "<p>Name<input name='pak["+fields+"][name]' type='text' id='pakName"+fields+"' class='pak'/></p>"+
                "<p>Count<input name='pak["+fields+"][count]' type='text' id='pakCount"+fields+"' class='pak'/></p>"+
                "<p>Price<input name='pak["+fields+"][Price]' type='text' id='pakPrice"+fields+"' class='pak'/></p>";
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Php side :

```
<?php
 print_r( $_POST['pak'] );
?>
```

The result :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [counter] => 1 [name] => [count] => [Price] => ) [1] => Array ( [counter] => 2 [name] => asd [count] => asd [Price] => asd ) )
```

Comment: Yup, it works now. Honestly, I don't know what syntax error it was before. Thanks anyway! :)